# Adding a UIButton to a UICollectionView cell programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIViewController with a UICollectionView created inside it programmatically. I want to add a button to the cell:

**viewDidLoad:**

```
UICollectionViewLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
_collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];

    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[EMCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
```

And then:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    EMCell *cell = (EMCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 60)];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:button];
    return cell;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're adding a button to the cell each time it is used.  You do understand that cells get reused, right?  Why don't you just add the button in your `EMCell` class's `init` method?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy the button doesn't show up.

Comment: Also, you should be adding the button as a subview of `cell.contentView`.

Comment: @robmayoff — adding the button as a subView con contentView in the cell, and initializing the button in the cell init method solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Add your button as a subview of `cell.contentView`.  Also, don't create the button every time `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called.  You might be reusing an existing cell that already has a button.   Better to add the button in your custom cell's `init` method instead.  Then just hide the button when you don't need it.