# Adding UIButtons on each uiimage of a UICollectionView cells programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIViewController with a UICollectionView image gallery created inside it programmatically. I want to add a button to the on each uiimage of UICollectionView cell:
The code in .h file is :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CMFViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@end
```

The code in .m file is :

```
#import "CMFViewController.h"
#import "CMFGalleryCell.h"

@interface CMFViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
@property (nonatomic) int currentIndex;

@end

@implementation CMFViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self loadImages];
    [self setupCollectionView];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UICollectionView methods

-(void)setupCollectionView {
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CMFGalleryCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
   /*
    UICollectionViewLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];

    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[CMFGalleryCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];*/
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.dataArray count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CMFGalleryCell *cell = (CMFGalleryCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *imageName = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setImageName:imageName];
   // [[cell myButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(myClickEvent:event) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 100.0, 20.0);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(show) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"ShowView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];





  //  NSMutableArray *buttonArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

  //  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       // NSUInteger index = arc4random() % 4;


        // newButton.frame = CGRectMake( 5,  5, 10, 10);    // Whatever position and size you need...

       // UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        //[newButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     //   [buttonArray addObject:newButton];
  //  }
   // newButton = buttonArray;   // Where myButtons is a NSArray property of your class, to store references to the buttons.

   // [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadImages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(updateCell) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell updateCell];

    return cell;

}
/*
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {

        // Create button

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
        [button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // add to contentView
        //[self.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    return self;
}*/
/*
-(void)updateCell
{

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self collectionView];

}*/
// INSERT DELETE BUTTON ACTION SNIPPET HERE

#pragma mark - delete for button


-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.collectionView.frame.size;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Data methods
-(void)loadImages {

    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Assets"];
    self.dataArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error:NULL];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Rotation handling methods

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:
(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    // Fade the collectionView out
    [self.collectionView setAlpha:0.0f];

    // Suppress the layout errors by invalidating the layout
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

    // Calculate the index of the item that the collectionView is currently displaying
    CGPoint currentOffset = [self.collectionView contentOffset];    
    self.currentIndex = currentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    // Force realignment of cell being displayed
    CGSize currentSize = self.collectionView.bounds.size;
    float offset = self.currentIndex * currentSize.width;
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(offset, 0)];

    // Fade the collectionView back in
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.125f animations:^{
        [self.collectionView setAlpha:1.0f];
    }];

}

@end
```

I have tied to get help from codes at following links
[adding-a-uibutton-to-a-uicollectionview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843533/adding-a-uibutton-to-a-uicollectionview-cell-programmatically)

[UIButton in cell in collection view not receiving touch up inside event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218208/uibutton-in-cell-in-collection-view-not-receiving-touch-up-inside-event?rq=1)
Please give my your suggestion and help me on this issue.

Comment: Where are you trying to add the button?

Comment: On each uiimageview in uicollectionview cell programmatically..

Comment: And where is that in the source code you have posted above?

Comment: In this function i have tried code from helping link: -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: Can you please edit your question and update the source to show us what you have tried?

Comment: now you can see my each attempt

Comment: from this link u can download code : http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/ their i want to place next and previous buttons on middle lines of each image of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think in `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` you are missing something like `[cell addSubview:button]` or `[cell.imageView addSubview:button]` or wherever you want to add the button to.

Comment: please get the code from the link in last comment make each image to navigate by adding side button....

Comment: I still can't see where you add the button as a subview in your collectionView datasource method. Sorry.