# Adding UIButtons to uiimage of a UICollectionView cells programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uiimage

I have a UIViewController with a UICollectionView image gallery created inside it programmatically. I want to add a button to the on each uiimage of UICollectionView cell: The code in CMFViewController.h.m file for adding button to imageview is:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CMFGalleryCell *cell = (CMFGalleryCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *imageName = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setImageName:imageName];
   // [[cell myButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(myClickEvent:event) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 100.0, 20.0);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(show) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"ShowView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  //  NSMutableArray *buttonArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

  //  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       // NSUInteger index = arc4random() % 4;


        // newButton.frame = CGRectMake( 5,  5, 10, 10);    // Whatever position and size you need...

       // UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        //[newButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     //   [buttonArray addObject:newButton];
  //  }
   // newButton = buttonArray;   // Where myButtons is a NSArray property of your class, to store references to the buttons.

   // [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadImages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(updateCell) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell updateCell];

    return cell;

}
```

I have tied to get help from codes at following links
[adding-a-uibutton-to-a-uicollectionview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843533/adding-a-uibutton-to-a-uicollectionview-cell-programmatically)

[UIButton in cell in collection view not receiving touch up inside event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218208/uibutton-in-cell-in-collection-view-not-receiving-touch-up-inside-event?rq=1)
Please give my your suggestion and help me on this issue.

from this link u can download [source code](https://github.com/timd/UICollectionViewGallery)  in [Creating a Paged Photo Gallery With a UICollectionView](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/):  their i want to place next and previous buttons on middle lines of each image of the screen

Comment: add button to cell. `[cell addSubview: button];`

Comment: please try it on source code for placing next and previous button on each image..i have tried [cell addSubview: button]; but it is not working..

Comment: Just do it in the cell's xib. Drag out two buttons and place them where you want on your image view. Give them centerY constraints, and whatever distance from the sides of the image view that you want.

Comment: button is showing in cell. i check source and add button. but if you want to use next previous functionality then you can also add button on `CMFViewController.xib`. you can also try @rdelmar comment.

Comment: @Wwwwwwwwwwwww i edited the code check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing next and previous buttons, don't added it on each image, better u add it on collection view, what chinttu-maddy-ramani told in his answer is correct, but he is doing in xib file, but programatically u can do it like below,

just add this code

**Edit for requirement updating the buttons**

in `CMFViewController.h` file make two button properties
replace by below code

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface CMFViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource,   UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *nextButton;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *prevButton;
 @end
```

in `CMFViewController.m` file

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self loadImages];
    [self setupCollectionView]; 
    [self addNextAndPreviousButtons];//add a method to add previous and next buttons 
 }

 //hear u are adding previous and next images, but i didn't added the constraints u add it if u want t work in both orientation 
 - (void)addNextAndPreviousButtons
 {
    _nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    _nextButton.frame =CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 50, 30);
    [_nextButton setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    _prevButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    _prevButton.frame =  CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 50, 30);
    [_prevButton setTitle:@"Prev" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_prevButton addTarget:self action:@selector(previousButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:_nextButton];
    [self.view addSubview:_prevButton];

}

 //previous button action
- (void)previousButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *visibleCell = [_collectionView visibleCells];
    if(visibleCell)
    {
      NSIndexPath *path = [_collectionView indexPathForCell:[visibleCell lastObject]];
      if(!path.row == 0)
      {
         NSIndexPath *nextPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:(path.row - 1) inSection:0];
         [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
     }
   }
}

//next button action
- (void)nextButtonAction:(id)sender  
{
    NSArray *visibleCell = [_collectionView visibleCells];
    if(visibleCell)
   {
      NSIndexPath *path = [_collectionView indexPathForCell:[visibleCell lastObject]];
     if(path.row < [_dataArray count] - 1)
     {
         NSIndexPath *nextPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:(path.row + 1) inSection:0];
         [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
    }
  }
}

//edited the method addNextAndPreviousButtons please replace it by this edited answer
//for all cases even when u are swiping 
//this is to handle buttons either by tapping or navigation through swiping the collection view 
- (void)updateButtons:(NSInteger)row
 {
    //at the beginning
    if(row == 0)
    {
      _prevButton.hidden = YES;
      _nextButton.hidden = NO;
      return;
    }
    else if(row == ([_dataArray count] -1))
    {
      _nextButton.hidden = YES;
      _prevButton.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
      _nextButton.hidden = NO;
      _prevButton.hidden = NO;
    }
 }

//finally u have to call updateButtons method  this method 
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
   CMFGalleryCell *cell = (CMFGalleryCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSString *imageName = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [cell setImageName:imageName];
   [cell updateCell];
   [self updateButtons:indexPath.row]; //update the buttons 
   return cell;

 }
```

Comment: Please change this code to hide previous button on ist image and next button on last image

Comment: put else condition below the if conditions and hide the corresponding buttons or disable user interactions

Comment: please code it...how i hide previous button for first image  and next button on last image –

Comment: yes.. :) wait  i am testing for all conditions wait

Comment: @Wwwwwwwwwwwww check it i edited if u have any problem just comment

Answer (score 0):

you can add button in you cell to direct drag & drop button in `CMFGalleryCell.xib` please check attach screenshot. and add button constraint to center horizontally and center vertically with your cell.

[image]

**for suggestion only** if you want next-previous functionality then you can also add button in main xib in `CMFViewController.xib` as per below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @Wwwwwwwwwwwww do you know how to drag and drop button in xib?